# Multiple variables loop and append dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to loop over 2 lists to get all combinations possible in the loop below. I have some difficulties to understand why the first part works and the second does not. Basically it query the same data but with all pattern from the lists. Any help would be very appreciated.

THE CODE:

```
base = ['BTC', 'ETH']
quoted = ['USDT', 'AUD','USD']

def daily_volume_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, all_data=False, limit=90, aggregate=1, exchange=''):
url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}'\
        .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate)
if exchange:
    url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
if all_data:
    url += '&allData=true'
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.json()['Data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
df.set_index('timestamp')
return df

## THIS CODE GIVES SOME DATA ##
volu = daily_volume_historical('BTC', 'USD', 'CCCAGG').set_index('timestamp').volumefrom

## THIS CODE GIVES EMPTY DATA FRAME ##
d_volu = [] 
for a,b in [(a,b) for a in base for b in quoted]:
  volu = daily_volume_historical(a, b, exchange= 'CCCAGG').volumefrom
  d_volu.append
d_volu = pd.concat(d_volu, axis=1)
```

`volu` output sample:

```
timestamp
2010-07-17 09:00:00        20.00
2010-07-18 09:00:00        75.01
2010-07-19 09:00:00       574.00
2010-07-20 09:00:00       262.00
2010-07-21 09:00:00       575.00
2010-07-22 09:00:00      2160.00
2010-07-23 09:00:00      2402.50
2010-07-24 09:00:00       496.32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools

base = ['BTC', 'ETH']
quoted = ['USDT', 'AUD','USD']

combinations = list(itertools.product(base, quoted))

def daily_volume_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, all_data=False,     limit=90, aggregate=1, exchange=''):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}'\
    .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate)
if exchange:
    url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
if all_data:
    url += '&allData=true'
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.json()['Data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
df.set_index('timestamp')
return df

## THIS CODE GIVES SOME DATA ##
volu = daily_volume_historical('BTC', 'USD',     'CCCAGG').set_index('timestamp').volumefrom

## THIS CODE GIVES EMPTY DATA FRAME ##
d_volu = [] 
for a,b in combinations:
volu = daily_volume_historical(a, b, exchange= 'CCCAGG').volumefrom
d_volu.append
d_volu = pd.concat(d_volu, axis=1)
```

Comment: or you can simply use : list(itertools.product(base, quoted))

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you provide details on how this should fit into the original code please?